# How to use css to style table for php iteration values

Tags: php, css, html-table

I am trying to create hailstone sequence table done in php.

Here is my simple code to produce the sequence:

```
<?php
            function HailstoneNumbers($x){
                static $c;
                echo $x." ";
                if ($x == 1 && $c == 0){
                    // N is initially 1.
                    echo "got 1!";
                    return $c;
                    }
                else if ($x == 1 && $c != 0){
                    // N is reduced to 1.
                    $c++;
                    echo "Done! number of steps = ",$c;
                    }
                else if ($x % 2 == 0){
                    // If N is Even.
                    $c++;
                    HailstoneNumbers((int)($x / 2));
                    }
                else if ($x % 2 != 0){
                    // N is Odd.
                    $c++;
                    HailstoneNumbers(3 * $x + 1);
                    }
                return $c;
                }
            $x = $_GET['x'];
            if(isset($_GET['x'])){
                $N = HailstoneNumbers($x);
            }
                ?>
```

It does the job of creating the values:

[image]

However, I want to create a table in this style:

[image]

it is 2 row and n columns where n is the total number of iteration.

The heading elements are in bold, and left entries and right entries are separated by a border.

Each entry has a border at its bottom except for the last entry.

I am quite new to php. I need to connect the number of steps to the number of columns and style it, but how do I create a css document for this?

Comment: Once you have added the HTML through your PHP you have the option of either having the CSS also inline - written by the PHP - or putting the CSS into a separate file. The first is simpler in a way but the latter is more flexible should you want to alter the layout. Which would you like?

Comment: I would say the having the css also inline.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some html. you can add borders css for exact look.

```
echo '<table style="border: 1px solid">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Iteration</td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';
function HailstoneNumbers($x){
    static $c = 0;
    // echo $x." ";
    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$c.'</td>
            <td>'.$x.'</td>
        </tr>';
    if ($x == 1 && $c == 0){
        // N is initially 1.
        echo "got 1!";
        return $c;
    }
    else if ($x == 1 && $c != 0){
        // N is reduced to 1.
        $c++;
        // echo "Done! number of steps = ",$c;
    }
    else if ($x % 2 == 0){
        // If N is Even.
        $c++;
        HailstoneNumbers((int)($x / 2));
    }
    else if ($x % 2 != 0){
        // N is Odd.
        $c++;
        HailstoneNumbers(3 * $x + 1);
    }
    return $c;
}
```